Mirroring specific files between multiple Azure Repos in different Projects
Here's the situation.

We use classic pipelines for auditing reasons. We are not allowed to use YAML.

We have multiple Lines of Business (LOB's). Each LOB is a member of a different Azure Project within the Organization. Each has it's own Repo.

I've written some generic scripts which pull in text files specific to each LOB when they run.

I would like to Sync the scripts BUT NOT the text files as they again are specific to the LOB. I cannot have the text files overwritten.


I am concerned that if I do not find a way to do this we will end up in a situation with various versions of the scripts running against the different lines of business. The Tasks I see in Azure seem to all sync the entire repo and not specific files. I'd like to be able to add a filter such as *.ps1 so that it only syncs the scripts.
I would like to be able to run a release pipeline that deploys the updated scripts to the different repos within the other Projects. I would like it to do this without also deploying (and overwriting) the text files.


I'd like to be able to add a filter such as *.ps1 so that it only syncs the scripts.

You can use Copy files task to achieve this. Add **/*.ps1 as content, and choose Overwrite option to overwrite if same named file.

Details below:

enable Allow scripts to access the OAuth token on agent job.


Add a powershell task to clone the target repo from another project:




After you pull all the script, put it in a folder, and then add copy files task as introduced above to copy the ps1 files.

Add a powershell task to push back the changes to target repo, it will only affect the changed ps1 files.



Since you are pushing repo with build service account([project scoped or collection scoped due to your project setting), make sure the build service account has contribute permission on target repo. and i add the account as contribute group of the target project.

Pipeline succeeds, ps1 files synced to target repo.

If you don't want subfolder1 which has the ps1 file, you can choose flatten folder option in copy files task.
